# Filtrar resultados de 2 tablas relacionadas en laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola tengo estas dos tablas relacionadas y esta funcion que me devuelve los campos que necesito de las tablas como puedo hacer una busqueda filtrada por uno o mas campos? he intentado hacerlo con el orwhere pero no funciona

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $name       = $request->get('first_name');
        $lastname   = $request->get('last_name');
        $dni        = $request->get('document_number');
        $cellphone  = $request->get('cellphone');
        $domicile   = $request->get('domicile');
        $cdcontract = $request->get('id');

        $name = 'agu';

        $contracts = Contract::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.contract_id', '=', 'contracts.id')
                    ->orwhere('affiliates.first_name', 'like','%'. $name .'%')
                    ->orwhere('affiliates.last_name', 'like','%'. $lastname .'%')
                    ->orwhere('contracts.cellphone', 'like','%'. $cellphone .'%')
                    ->orwhere('contracts.domicile', 'like','%'. $domicile .'%')
                    ->orwhere('contracts.document_number', $dni)
                    ->orwhere('contracts.id', 'like','%'. $cdcontract .'%')
                    ->get();

        return $contracts->map(function ($contract) {
            return [
                'id' => $contract->id,
                'number' => $contract->full_number,
                'holder_last_name' => $contract->holder->last_name,
                'holder_first_name' => $contract->holder->first_name,
                'domicile' => $contract->domicile,
                'phone' => $contract->phone,
                'cellphone' => $contract->cellphone,
                'branch' => $contract->branch->name,
                'current_fee' => $contract->current_fee,
            ];
        })->toArray();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este error me aparece en el storage/log/laravel.log

local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'contracts.document_number' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `contracts` inner join `affiliates` on `affiliates`.`contract_id` = `contracts`.`id` where (`affiliates`.`first_name` like %agu% or `affiliates`.`last_name` like %% or `contracts`.`cellphone` like %% or `contracts`.`domicile` like %% or `contracts`.`document_number` is null or `contracts`.`id` like %%) and `contracts`.`deleted_at` is null) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'contracts.document_number' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `contracts` inner join `affiliates` on `affiliates`.`contract_id` = `contracts`.`id` where (`affiliates`.`first_name` like %agu% or `affiliates`.`last_name` like %% or `contracts`.`cellphone` like %% or `contracts`.`domicile` like %% or `contracts`.`document_number` is null or `contracts`.`id` like %%) and `contracts`.`deleted_at` is null) at C:\xampp\htdocs\osdam - copia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664, Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'contracts.document_number' in 'where clause' at C:\xampp\htdocs\osdam - copia\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:63, PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'contracts.document_number' in 'where clause' at C:\xampp\htdocs\osdam - copia\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:61)
[stacktrace]

Comment: Por favor formatea el código como `codigo` y no como imagen. También recuerda que si dices "no funciona", debes aclarar qué es lo que no funciona : - si da un error, mostrar el error. - si no obtienes el resultado esperado, cual es el resultado obtenido

Comment: ya hice los cambios

Comment: ok, la imagen que muestras del error en el navegador es un status 500, o sea un mensaje genérico de error en el servidor. Para ver de que se trata debes mirar en los logs de Laravel que están en el archivo `/storage/logs/laravel.log` de tu proyecto.

Comment: Seguro que la columna contracts_number existe? Además de eso es alguna llave primaria dicha columna?

Comment: ya lo resolvi puse mal el nombre de una columna, pero el filtro sigue sin funcionar, me traer todos los registros

Comment: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping) "Siempre debe agrupar las llamadas orWhere para evitar un comportamiento inesperado cuando se aplican ámbitos globales."  Prueba poniendo los orWhere dentro de un where, como en el ejemplo de la documentación

Comment: ya lo resolvi tenia que cambiar los orwhere por where

Answer (score 0):

problema resuelto:

estaba asi:

```
$contracts = Contract::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.contract_id', '=', 'contracts.id')
                    ->orwhere('affiliates.first_name', 'like','%'. $name .'%')
                    ->orwhere('affiliates.last_name', 'like','%'. $lastname .'%')
                    ->orwhere('contracts.cellphone', 'like','%'. $cellphone .'%')
                    ->orwhere('contracts.domicile', 'like','%'. $domicile .'%')
                    ->orwhere('contracts.document_number', $dni)
                    ->orwhere('contracts.id', 'like','%'. $cdcontract .'%')
                    ->get();
```

ahora esta asi: solo hay cambiar los orwhere por where y utiliza 1 o varios filtros

```
$contracts = Contract::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.contract_id', '=', 'contracts.id')
                    ->where('affiliates.first_name', 'like','%'. $name .'%')
                    ->where('affiliates.last_name', 'like','%'. $lastname .'%')
                    ->where('contracts.cellphone', 'like','%'. $cellphone .'%')
                    ->where('contracts.domicile', 'like','%'. $domicile .'%')
                    ->where('contracts.document_number', $dni)
                    ->where('contracts.id', 'like','%'. $cdcontract .'%')
                    ->get();
```