# Realizar busqueda OR where en laravel

Tags: laravel

hola tengo las siguientes 3 tablas en mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo quiero hacer es un busqueda filtrada de la siguiente manera pero en el controlador de laravel:

```
@idcontracto
@nombre
@apellido
@domicilio
@sucursal
@celular

    select Contracts.id, affiliates.first_name, affiliates.last_name, Contracts.domicile, 
    branches.name, Contracts.cellphone, Contracts.phone, Contracts.current_fee  
    from Contracts inner join affiliates on affiliates.id_contract=Contract.id  inner join 
    branches on branches.id=affiliates.branch_id where Contracts.id=@idcontracto 
    or affiliates.first_name='%'.@nombre.'%' or `affiliates.last_name='%'.@apellido.'%' or 
    Contracts.domicile='%'.@domicilio.'%' or branches.name 'like' '%'.@sucursal.'%' or 
    Contracts.cellphone=@celular`
```

lo que necesito es que me busque todos los registros que compartan el o los mismos valores(si ingreso un nombre que traiga todos los registros que tengan el mismo nombre, si ingreso una sucursal que me traiga todos los registro de esa sucursal, si envio nombre y apellido que me traiga todos los registros que tengan el mismo nombre y apellido)

Comment: Pero cuál es la duda ¿cómo construir la consulta con Eloquent o cuál es?

Comment: si era eso como hacer la consulta en eloquent

Comment: Para poder ayudarte con la consulta de Eloquent, tendrías que publicar los modelos de las tablas para saber como se llaman los mismos y sus relaciones. Por otro lado, veo que tenés mal referenciados algunos campos: `affiliates.id_contract` se llama `contract_id`, `branches.id = affiliates.branch_id`, `branch_id` no está en `affiliates`, está en `contracts`.

Comment: en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/301303/filtrar-resultados-de-2-tablas-relacionadas-en-laravel decías que lo habías resuelto. Si no es así arregla esa pregunta/respuesta para no confundir a otros. Recuerda arrobar al usuario para responder un comentario para que le llegue una notificación y se entere de que le estas respondiendo (por ej @AgustinCoronel)

Comment: perdon pero solo funcionaba con ciertos registros, no me funcionaba bien, pero ahora si funciona, pude encotrar otra forma de hacerlo funcioanr

Answer (score 0):

La consulta en eloquent la construyes a partir de los modelos. y digamos que en este caso el modelo que hace referencia la tabla **Contracts** se llama **Contract**, la consulta la puedes construir de la siguiente forma.

```
$contracts=Contract::selects('Contracts.id','affiliates.first_name','affiliates.last_name','...Y así con cada uno de los campos que quieres mostrar...')
->join('affiliates','affiliates.id_contract','=','Contract.id')->join('branches','branches.id','=','affiliates.branch_id')
->where('Contracts.id','=',$idcontracto)->orWhere('affiliates.first_name','=',$nombre)
->orWhere('affiliates.last_name','=',$apellido)->orWhere('Contracts.domicile','=',$domicilio)
->orWhere('branches.name','like','%'.$sucursal.'%')->orWhere('Contracts.cellphone','=',$celular)->get();
```

También puedes hacer que tu consulta se construya de forma dinámica según los valores que tengas, Ejemplo:

```
$contracts=Contract::selects('Contracts.id','affiliates.first_name','affiliates.last_name','...Y así con cada uno de los campos que quieres mostrar...')
->join('affiliates','affiliates.id_contract','=','Contract.id')->join('branches','branches.id','=','affiliates.branch_id')
->where('Contracts.id','=',$idcontracto);

if($nombre)
    $contracts=$contracts->orWhere('affiliates.first_name','=',$nombre);

if($apellido)
      $contracts=$contracts->orWhere('affiliates.last_name','=',$apellido);

if($domicilio)
      $contracts=$contracts->orWhere('Contracts.domicile','=',$domicilio);


$contracts=$contracts->get();
```

en este [enlace] [https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries][1](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries), puedes encontrar mas opciones que te permiten armar distintas consultas sql, desde las mas sencillas hasta las mas elaboradas.